# Acá estoy, yo, la Callas… English translation

Tags: traducción

Is the following translation correct?

> Here I am, me, the Callas...

or

> Here I am, it's me, the Callas...

Or, not sure... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the first one, since that "yo" in `Acá estoy, yo, la Callas` is stressing a reference to self.

The option with `Here I am, it's me`, since it has that "it's" would be closer to "Acá estoy, **soy** yo, la Callas".

Not that there is much distance between one and another, but if you add that "it's" then in Spanish you'll likely have a verb too (and viceversa).